# how to set environment on ubuntu for the first time?

Tags: ubuntu, operating-system, ubuntu-19.04

I just installed

> ubuntu desktop version 19

but I can't install the

> HYPODD

program on it.
when I type command '`make`' it gave:

> make[1]: g77: Command not found

I installed the `gfortran` but nothing changed. Is the problem in setting the environment?
If so, how can I set an environment for the first time after just installing `ubuntu 19`?

Comment: Is there a setting in the Makefile to set the Fortran compiler? Try setting that to "gfortran" Additionally, are you sure you are trying to install v1.3, which is explicitly noted to be "gfortran" compatible?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'am trying to install HypoDD program v1.3 and the first lines in the makefile are as follows: "CMD = ph2dt
CC = gcc
FC = g77
#FC = f77
#FC = gfortran"   note that I'am new with lineux

Answer (score 0):

The g77 compiler has to be installed and the path and the environment van be set via typing on terminal the command 
$ gedit ~/.bashrc 
and adding the path of the new profram